# How can one overwrite the return address without buffers on on the stack?

Tags: c, linux, disassembly, buffer-overflow

In the below program, I have a few buffers, but they are global variables, not stored on the stack.  Thus, I'm not seeing a viable way of overwriting the return address to execute a shellcode.

Is there a vulnerability in the below that I am missing?  The path constructed in snprintf seems pretty solid - not seeing a way to redirect the execution path.

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>

char buffer[256] = "";
char filename[256] = "";


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  setreuid(geteuid(), geteuid());
  setregid(getegid(), getegid());

  if (argv[1]) {
    snprintf(filename, 255, "/var/smash/g6/%s", basename(argv[1]));
    printf("Checking filename %s\n", filename);
    if (access(filename, X_OK)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "You do not have the permission to execute this file\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please provide the program name. Currently available programs:\n");
    system("/bin/ls /var/smash/v6");
    return 2;
  }

  if (argv[2]) {
    strcpy(buffer, argv[2]);
  }
  else {
    printf("Provide the parameter(s):\n");
    gets(buffer); 
  }
  printf("Executing filename %s\n", filename);

  execlp(filename, filename, buffer, (char *)0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By overflowing `buffer`, you can overwrite `filename` with an arbitrary command, and then it will be `execlp`-ed.

Comment: Any code that uses `gets` is very vulnerable.

Comment: @kaylum This one is vulnerable even without it.

Answer (score 3):

Without trying it, it looks as if the vulnerability is that you provide a `filename`, which is checked to see that you have access, but then you read a string that isn't constrained to `buffer` but can overflow into `filename` such that your program will then execute the new `filename` without being constrained by the earlier checks.